# Mongodb - convert string toDate inside an array using updateMany

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection document looks like this. I would like to convert `"due_date"` from string to date format using `"$toDate"`.

```json
{
    "item": 1,
    "checklist": [{
        "due_date": null,
        "is_completed": false,
        "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
        "due_date": "2021-11-16T00:45:54.685Z",
        "is_completed": false,
        "is_deleted": false
    },
    ]
}, 
{
    "item": 2,
    "checklist": [{
        "due_date": "",
        "is_completed": false,
        "is_deleted": false
    },
    {
        "due_date": "2022-1-16T00:45:54.685Z",
        "is_completed": false,
        "is_deleted": false
    },
    ]
}
```

I was able to convert empty string to `null` using this query.

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  "checklist.due_date": ""
},
{
  "$set": {
    "checklist.$[check].due_date": null
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "check.due_date": ""
    }
  ]
})
```

When I try to update the date using similar method, it saves `"$$checklist.due_date"` in string format instead of actual date.

```js
db.collection.updateMany({
  "checklist.due_date": {
    "$type": "string",
    "$ne": ""
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "checklist.$[check].due_date": {
      $toDate: "$$checklist.due_date"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "check.due_date": {
        "$type": "string",
        "$ne": ""
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I have tried `"$map"` to update `"due_date"` but don't know how to filter out `null` values inside the object. It is giving me error while converting null values.
[How to update date string in array to date format in mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388412/how-to-update-date-string-in-array-to-date-format-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the conversion with `$convert` and set `onError` and `onNull` clauses to cater the null and empty string values. Use `$map` to perform the operation on all array elements.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "checklist": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$checklist",
          "as": "cl",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$cl",
              {
                due_date: {
                  "$convert": {
                    "input": "$$cl.due_date",
                    "to": "date",
                    "onError": null,
                    "onNull": null
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hh9PijFiemG) for your reference.